# piping no vs yes to shell confirmation

Tags: bash, shell

I am interested in a way to pipe no into confirmation

consider example

```
$ touch ff fff
$ mv ff fff
mv: overwrite 'fff'?
```

one can pipe 'yes' to avoid answering to confirmation prompt (to positively resolve it beforehand)

```
$ touch ff fff
$ yes | mv ff fff
mv: overwrite 'fff'? renamed 'ff' -> 'fff'
```

my question is: **is there a way to resolve it with negative answer?**
something like

```
$ no | mv ff fff
zsh: command not found: no
mv: overwrite 'fff'? %
```

here problem is that piping no returns error, which can be annoying for
`set -e` scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yes` can print a different string:

```
$ yes n | mv ff fff
```

However, it is better to look for flags that will do this rather than script your way through interactive prompts. Most programs have such options. `mv` has `-f` for force and `-n` for no clobber:

```
$ mv -f ff fff   # force overwrite
$ mv -n ff fff   # never overwrite
```

Comment: My `mv` from GNU coreutils 8.30 ignores `no` from stdin.

Comment: The better still is to read the man page! ...